# How to detect if mouse left the window in Angular way?

Tags: angular, mouseevent, mouseleave

I want to detect if the mouse left the browser window and not just a specific div therefore not using the (mouseleave) etc. methods in HTML. Is there a way?

> UPDATE:

***ParentComponent:***

```
<div class="parent" (dragover)="openDialogComponent()"></div>

@HostListener('window:dragleave') onMouseLeave() {
    console.log('leave window?');
}
```

***What actually happens:***
When files are dragged over ParentComponent, DialogComponent opens. When files are dragged over DialogComponent, it closes because it left ParentComponent area thus giving a flickering effect on the popup.

***What I want to happen:*** How do you close DialogComponent when mouse leaves both Parent and Dialog components, or in other words, when mouse/drag events leave the BROWSER/WHOLE WINDOW?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HostListener` for this,

```
@HostListener('window:mouseleave', ['$event.target']) onMouseLeave() {
    // do something
}
```

> The key is the DOM event that the directive listens to. To listen to global events, add the target to the event name. The target can be window, document or body.

Refer the [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host).

Comment: but doesn't it only work for components and not the window as a whole?

Comment: For global events, give the target in the `hostlistener`. Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala It does not work when I give the `window` target in the `hostlistener` but work if I did not